# Delete mysql rows if contains certain content not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-like

I am using the following script to purge spam links from my guestbook, if I copy and past the query into phpmyadmin it works just fine, if I run the following script in my browser saved as a php file I get the error "Couldn't execute query:". I have had a look over it and cant see what iv done wrong, can anyone see anything glaringly obvious iv missed ?.

```
    <?php
    // Checks to see if the key value is set
    if (isset($_GET['key'])) {
        $key = $_GET['key'];
    }
    // If the key value isnt set give it a value of nothing
    else
    {$key = '';}

    // Checks to see if the key value is valid to authenticate the user
    if ($key == 'keycode'){
    // If the key value is correct the user is granted access
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    // Select mysql db
    mysql_select_db("towerroa_TRA", $con);
    mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM `itsnb_phocaguestbook_items` WHERE `content` LIKE '%<a%'")or die ("Couldn't execute query: ".mysqli_error());

    echo 'Spam Purged !';
    }
    else {
    // Denies the user access if the key value isnt correct 
    echo '<h1>Access Denied !</h1>';}
```

Comment: And what is the error in your couldnt execute query? Also you are using the deprecated `mysql_` function everywhere, exept for the `mysqli_query` part. Change everything to `mysql_*` queries or `mysqli_*` queries. The `mysqli_` is highly advised!

Comment: There is no error funnily enough, just that it cant execute the query.

Comment: Instead of $con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password"); TRY $con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password") or die(mysql_error()); - Does this give you any error? Is mysqli_query in your code intended to be mysql_query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is you are mixing up `mysql_` and `mysqli_`. Try fixing the below;

```
mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password");
mysqli_select_db("towerroa_TRA", $con);
mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM `itsnb_phocaguestbook_items` WHERE `content` LIKE '%<a%'")or die ("Couldn't execute query: ".mysqli_error());
```

Instead of;

```
mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
mysql_select_db("towerroa_TRA", $con);
mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM `itsnb_phocaguestbook_items` WHERE `content` LIKE '%<a%'")or die ("Couldn't execute query: ".mysqli_error());
```

Comment: Iv tried this and still get the "Couldn't execute query:" error message :-(

Comment: Have you **triple** checked all the DB names, table names and user/password etc? And what is the part of the error message after the `:`?

Answer (score 2):

```
mysqli_select_db("towerroa_TRA", $con);
```

should be

```
mysqli_select_db($con,"towerroa_TRA");
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace all `mysql_*` function with `mysqli_*`

Comment: Iv tried this and still get the "Couldn't execute query:" error message :-(

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php
// Checks to see if the key value is set
if (isset($_GET['key'])) {
    $key = $_GET['key'];
}
// If the key value isnt set give it a value of nothing
else
{$key = '';}

// Checks to see if the key value is valid to authenticate the user
if ($key == 'keycode'){
// If the key value is correct the user is granted access
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

// Select mysql db
mysql_select_db("towerroa_TRA", $con);
mysql_query($con, "DELETE FROM `itsnb_phocaguestbook_items` WHERE `content` LIKE '%<a%'")or die ("Couldn't execute query: ".mysql_error());

echo 'Spam Purged !';
}
else {
// Denies the user access if the key value isnt correct 
echo '<h1>Access Denied !</h1>';}
```